# How is this possible using partial method with .NET framework 2.0 in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to know I am using Visual Studio 2019 and selecting .NET framework 2.0. After that, I am trying to use the partial method - how is this possible? Because the partial method was introduced in C# 3 and is this available with .NET 2.0? Visual Studio is not showing any errors ...

While I am using Visual Studio 2012 for the same means when I select .NET 2.0 and ISO-2, then Visual Studio shows errors for partial method but why does Visual Studio 2019 not show anything?

Please help me, thank you

Comment: .net core 2.0 is using C# 7.0. Or you really mean dot net framework 2.0 from 15 years ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial methods is a language feature, not a framework feature. They determine how code is compiled but the IL generated is still the same as was used back when .NET Framework 2.0 was new either way. If a partial method is not implemented then it's as though there's no method at all and if it is implemented then it's exactly like any other method.

When using a particular IDE, your projects will use the latest available language version unless you specify otherwise. This means that using a newer version of VS will use a newer version of C#, even if you target an older version of .NET. If you use an older version of VS then it will not know about the newer language version so newer language features will not be available.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to differentiate between **runtime** and **compiler** features.

The compiler compiles your C# source code into IL Bytecode, which the runtime then runs, using the libraries that the target Framework provides. So you are limited by what the runtime can support - but the compiler can do a lot more since it can transform your source code however it wants before compiling it into IL bytecode.

You can use a newer compiler and tell it to emit code to run on .NET Framework 2.0 (*1), like for example partial methods.

Partial methods are purely compiler things. This code here:

```cs
using System;

partial class A
{
    partial void OnSomethingHappened(string s);
}

// This part can be in a separate file.
partial class A
{
    partial void OnSomethingHappened(String s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something happened: {0}", s);
    }
}
```

gets [translated by the compiler to this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALAPgAgJgIwFgBQ64GYAEAHAQwCcAXASwIBsdEcBBdAb3R1f2PKpqhwHkA7AMoB7ALYBTEgAsy/AOYAJAnjzj+4gCYAKOEgAMOAM4BKANzoAvunQB6GzgAqMw+1I4AxgX45g4nLJwCI3FCIgISPwAzMkpxADpMXFDOaloGNGY0NlcU7j4hMUkZeSUVNU0tQRIiWTkjYxY2TOzs3QBOLQAiEQlpWpwpZVV1DRAcRj0LToAaevMstis0CyA) - which no longer contains anything related to partial methods, because it's all resolved well before the runtime has to execute it:

```cs
internal class A
{
    private void OnSomethingHappened(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something happened: {0}", s);
    }
}
```

In fact, it would be possible - in theory - to use C# 10 features like record types, because they are [just regular classes with a whole lot of methods just auto-created by the compiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABAzAAlpKAExwDEIIAKDARgAYcAhAQygEocBvHAXyA). I don't think that a compiler that understands C# 10 and can emit IL bytecode for .NET Framework 2.0 exists, but in theory, there's nothing stopping someone from making one (*2).

It's not always possible to make certain newer features work with an older runtime, and sometimes there are some really big caveats (for example, `Span<T>` on .NET Framework works, but with significantly worse performance characteristics than on newer .NET 5+ versions) - so there's no hard and fast rule which features will and will not work with newer compilers on older runtimes.

---

(*1) I assume you really mean the ancient .NET Framework 2.0 from 2005, but the answer still stands for any version of .NET, or really, for most programming languages out there that work with an intermediary representation.

(*2) Or even one targeting the original .NET Framework 1.0 from 2002, but the lack of Generics is really going to hurt.

Comment: "I don't think that a compiler that understands C# 10 and can emit IL bytecode for .NET Framework 2.0 exists" Until pretty recently I was still building for .NET Framework 3.5, which is just .NET Framework 2 plus some libraries, IIRC. I needed to use some additional build config to make it work: but that was just a few lines of csproj

Comment: @MarcGravell Interesting, for some reason I thought that Roslyn no longer targeted NetFx <4 and that csc was no longer updated with new language features since Roslyn, but it looks like I'm completely wrong about that. But I just saw that [.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is supported until Jan 9, 2029](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework) (Probably because it technically still ships with Windows Server 2022?), so i guess it makes sense to still be targetable my modern compilers.